# Can I transfer my War Robots progress from Android to iOS?

Tags: ios, war-robots

So this is a basic question - can you get your Google Play account linked to a game on an Apple Device (iPad Air to be exact)?
What I'm trying to do is to use my google play account with a save file of War Robots to load on the War Robots on my Ipad. Is this possible? Couldn't find a question like this anywhere.

Is there any way to transfer my War Robots game data to my Ipad?

Answer (score 1):

According to a  War Robots support article found at https://pixonic.helpshift.com/a/war-robots/?s=progress-item-or-currency-loss&f=how-do-i-transfer-my-in-game-progress-to-another-device&l=en&p=web:

> Keep in mind that currently War Robots does not support cross-platform play, so it is only possible to transfer your progress to the device that works on the same OS as your current one.

Other games might support this sort of transfer, but War Robots unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: Oof, that's a bummer.. Still, thanks for answering!